# Macbook pro 13 - Sound comes from speakers instead of headphones

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, audio, headphones, speakers

Recently there appeared an issue when I plug my headphones into 3.5 output, the sound does not come from headphones instead it comes from the internal speakers.

The strangest thing is that Mac recognizes headphones when I plug them and changes the output in the settings automatically as it should, from speakers to headphones. But still for some reason sound comes from speakers.

I have also tried manually changing outputs, it seems to have no effect.

Mac OS 10.15.2

Comment: "changes the input in the settings" shouldn't it be "output"? What app are you using? Some apps have their own audio input/output setting.

Comment: @amdyes Sorry, my bad. Changed to output. I am using Google Chrome. Also I tried the system sounds in the sound settings(Sound effects tab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was fixed by itself. Mac froze for some reason, I forced it to reboot, the problem was fixed.

Comment: You lucked out. I have this problem in Chrome but not iTunes or Safari, and on both our Macs. Like yours, plugging in headphones changes the sound output selection but not the sound output in Chrome. Rebooting, resetting PRAM, changing MIDI Setup, ... doesn't help. It seems like a software bug in the complexity of sound output devices

Comment: @Jerry101 as I remember the sound problem was actual on any program, not just Chrome. Might be a different problem

Answer (score 0):

You have the exact opposite symptom, but exact same problem as described in the question [Force sound's output on speakers](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/262779/force-sounds-output-on-speakers/262783#262783).

**Basically, the audio jack is broken**.  There’s a *physical* switch that’s stuck in “speaker mode” and it cannot be switched via software.

You can get around this by using a USB or Bluetooth microphone/headset or use a [USB DAC](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/259681/119271) or [USB Mixer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/295628/119271) if using a “pro grade” mic.

Comment: But as I said the switching happens normally, it displays correctly that headphones are now connected. But the problem is that it still plays from internal speakers, not from headphones.

Comment: Yes...I understand exactly what you're saying.  It's a *hardware* issue.  Think about it...software says it's going to headphones, but it's going to speakers.  You can't override software that's no longer properly controlling the hardware.  It's got to go in for service.